# Sharepoint 2010 How to use "File Size" column value in a formula?

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to use "File Size" (aka "FileSizeDisplay") in a Calculated column formula.

"File Size" is an existing column (default SP not custom).
But is not available in the "Insert Column" list of any library.
And SP displays an error message that states it does not exist if it is added to a formula manually as either [File Size] or [FileSizeDisplay].

All I want to do is inform a user that an image is too big. Not trying to prohibit file size upload or anything technical like that. Just want a Calculated column to display a message.
If the column value was available the following would work:

```
=IF([File Size]>50000,"Image is too big","Image is sized correctly")
```

or

```
=IF([FileSizeDisplay]>50000,"Image is too big","Image is sized correctly")
```

Any one know why this column is not available?

Cheers

Comment: Perhaps this is better suited for http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to get the file size first: [get file size](http://www.dotnetperls.com/fileinfo-length) then you can display of message in a pop up or how ever you'd like

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // The name of the file
    const string fileName = "test.txt";

    // Create new FileInfo object and get the Length.
    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(fileName);
    long s1 = f.Length;

    // Change something with the file. Just for demo.
    File.AppendAllText(fileName, " More characters.");

    // Create another FileInfo object and get the Length.
    FileInfo f2 = new FileInfo(fileName);
    long s2 = f2.Length;

    // Print out the length of the file before and after.
    Console.WriteLine("Before and after: " + s1.ToString() +
        " " + s2.ToString());

    // Get the difference between the two sizes.
    long change = s2 - s1;
    Console.WriteLine("Size increase: " + change.ToString());
    }
}
```